# What can I change in my code to get my Quicksort function working? (Using struct and arrays to sort last name)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct, quicksort

I am trying to use Quicksort to sort the last names in a struct array alphabetically, but something seems to be a little off with my code because my output sometimes is wrong, it generally sorts the names in the right order, but it doesn't always and I have no idea why. Can anyone please help me find an error with my code? Any feedback helps, thank you.

```
void nameSort(Person* array, int size) {
    quickSort(array, 0, size-1);
}
```

I added the function below to help my nameSort function, it uses Quicksort to sort the last names alphabetically from my array (and if the last names are the same, sort through the first names).

```
void quickSort(Person* array, int left, int right) {
    int i, j;
    const char *x;
    const char *y;
    struct Person temp;
i = left;
j = right;
x = array[(left+right)/2].last.c_str();
y = array[(left+right)/2].first.c_str();

do {
    if (array[i].last == array[j].last) {
        while ((strcmp(array[i].first.c_str(), y) < 0) && (i < right)) i++;
        while ((strcmp(array[j].first.c_str(), y) > 0) && (j > left)) j--;
    }
    while ((strcmp(array[i].last.c_str(), x) < 0) && (i < right)) i++;
    while ((strcmp(array[j].last.c_str(), x) > 0) && (j > left)) j--;
    if (i <= j) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        i++; j--;
    }
}
while (i <= j);
if (left < j) quickSort(array, left, j);
if (i < right) quickSort(array, i, right);
```

}

Comment: Why are you using low-level `strcmp` instead of using `std::string::operator <`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Probably because C++ is a mess and it's tedious to find the right tool for the right job, especially if you don't have much experience? So, new people and inexperienced programmers may just tend to use what they know.

Comment: @nbro -- But the right tool in this case is the most obvious tool.  Just compare strings using `<`, just like any other basic type.  No need for calls to `strcmp`, no calls to `c_str()`, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah, I understand. The problem is that many people (e.g. many articles online, etc) still teach C++ as an improved C, so you end up doing all sorts of things (maybe because you think it's faster, maybe because who knows).

Comment: So, in other words, I think your comment should not have been a question, but a suggestion ;)

Comment: In the meantime, there is no question at all into the OP question. At best, the answer will only be relevant to OP. It should be improved first to ask about an aspect of that code instead of «Why is that code not working?».

Comment: The whole point of having standard libraries is so you don't have to debug this sort of low-level stuff: http://rextester.com/LGE61253

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's required for homework (or something on that order) you shouldn't be using `strcmp` to do your comparisons, nor should you be writing your own `Quicksort`.

If you want to sort some structures, you probably want to use `std::sort`:

```
struct person { 
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    // ... probably more stuff here

    bool operator<(person const &other) const { 
       if (last == other.last)
           return first < other.first;
       return last < other.last;
    }
};

std::vector<person> people;

// code to put some people's names into `people` goes here

std::sort(people.begin(), people.end());

// print out the sorted list:
for (auto const &p : people)
    std::cout << p.last << ", " << p.first << "\n";
```

If you provide an overload of `operator<` for the type being sorted, `std::sort` will use that by default (via `std::less<T>`). If want to sort by some other field, you can specify how you want the comparison done:

```
struct person {
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
    time_t birth;
};

// sort the people by age/birthday:  
std::sort(people.begin(), people.end(), 
     [](auto const &a, auto const &b) { return a.birth < b.birth; });
```

Comment: Does not answer the 'question'.

Comment: @user2864740; Nope, it just answers the question he should have asked. :-)

Comment: I can't argue against that, but only 19 points for the offhand-answer :}

Comment: There is no question yet so there is no good answer. I'd make the OP work a little to have a good question bit if he wants good answers. The question being in its current state, this answer is more of a comment and slightly a guess IMO. If the question was decently asked and in the anticipated direction, I would agree, though.